# Примеры CMS с отличной панелью управления. На ваш взгляд

Tags: cms, админка

Потихоньку делаю вышеозначенную панель управления сайтом для движка. Так как я могу напрямую менять код, то особой нужды в панели нету. Но хочется сделать, и сделать хорошо.

В каких CMS, по вашему мнению, панель управления идеальна?
Хотелось бы их "пощупать", и сделать нечто подобное.

Comment: кстати, а что значить "панель управления сайтом для движка" ?

Comment: некий инструмент, который позволил бы настраивать и редактировать сайт человеку, незнакомому с программированием.

Comment: Bitrix. У нас в компании прижился только он. Работать смогли все и маркетологи и пиарщики. Главное все рассказать, показать.

Comment: Ну например ucoz ^^

Comment: да, мне в укозе все достаточно интуитивно понятно, где что редактировать )

Answer (score 2):

У UMI.CMS довольно приятная админка, но сама система дико тормознутая пока что.
В админке bitrix я вообще ничего не понял, да и шаблонизатор у них туповат.
В принципе hostcms как то видел, понравилась возможность править шаблоны из админки, хоть это и небезопасно, но зато иногда очень полезно.

Comment: @Deadik, Bitrix'ом нужно заниматься. Так как мы тут все программисты нам проще написать свое чем изучать чужое -)

Comment: Ну в последнее время всё больше склоняюсь к тому что от коробочных систем вообще нужно потихоньку отказываться, а то их "универсальность" делает их очень тормознутыми

Comment: @Deadik, рынок требует коробочные продукты которые можно будет внедрить с минимальными вложениями. Так что никто от них отказываться не будет. По опыту могу сказать, что лучше ковыряться в платной CMS у которой есть тех поддержка которая в более менее адекватные сроки может оказать поддержку чем сидеть и вкуривать сырцы какого-то доморощенного велосипедиста изучая его быдлокод.

Comment: @huffman, битрикс это и есть  говнокод.

Не важно что рынок требует.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, я бы очень хотел посмотреть на ваш код -)))

Comment: @huffman Абсолютно согласен, сами сейчас собираем сайты только на коробках, рынок требует быстрой реализации. Однако этого требует не весь рынок, есть более узкий сегмент который требует более грамотного подхода к архитектуре, где использование коробочного решения просто неприемлемо и нужно расти профессионально до уровня таких проектов, а для этого стоит понемногу отказываться от CMS.

Comment: @Deadik, так никто же не говорит, что давайте делать все из коробки. Мы в споре забыли он вопросе. "Примеры CMS с отличной панелью управления. На ваш взгляд." На мой взгляд это Bitrix!

Comment: @huffman, Я бы тебе показал:-) Но ты не поймешь:))))

Answer (score 0):

идеальная панель управления - отсутствующая панель управления. это моя мысль.

но это все субъективно. делай как представляешь сам.

Comment: Если в моем случае - то да. Я могу код напрямую править. А если я делаю сайт для кого-то далекого от кодинга?

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится Netcat. (Это платная цмс, но у них есть беслатные демоверсии, так что можно в них посмотреть на эту цмс изнутри).

Comment: Даже не достойна смотреть её - http://habrahabr.ru/post/37647/

Comment: ну, допустим, я не буду утверждать, что это офигенно сделанная система, но статья на хабре от 2008 года,  и с тех пор в этой цмс уже много всего переписали.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, я бы на вашем месте обратил внимание на дату статьи "21 августа 2008 в 13:17" с тех пор NetCat сдорово причесали. Почему я так говорю? Потому, что не так давно работал с этой CMS. Это конечно не Bitrix но тоже не плох.

Comment: @huffman, Окей, я проверю. Но битрикс это костыли.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, по поводу битрикс не согласен с вами. Вы когда его в последний раз трогали? Я трогал последнюю версию пру месяцев назад. Все там вполне достойно.

Answer (score -1):

Bitrix.

Comment: Очень плохо.

Comment: чем плохо то? Тем что вы сами такое сделать не сможете? -)

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, ну предложите свою или опровергните, но с объяснениями. По моему мнению, Bitrix хорош, но для малого проекта слишком наворочен. В нем все продумано для оптимизации, он идет в ногу со временем. Люди, разрабатывающие его, не глупые, если бы какие-то компоненты пользователей не устраивали, их бы не писали. Правда я в нем чуть ногу не сломала, пока разобралась что к чему, но это дело привычки. Многие из его "примочек" я использовала на своем движке. Хотя некоторых администрируемых модулей, необходимых мне для разработки сайтов, в нем нет.

Comment: @MyNameIs, 

     global $SHOWIMAGEFIRST;
     $SHOWIMAGEFIRST = true;
     $this->content .= '<table width="100%" cellspacing="4"   cellpadding="8">';

Какаябылабы не красивая говнокодерская сms, она остается говнокодерской. Не нужно её смотреть.

Comment: номер версии, название файла?

Comment: @MyNameIs,  удобная панель просто чтобы была? Та хотя бы wordpress. Хотя конечно я иее не использую.

Comment: Самая удобная - это, конечно же моя -) А вот теневых функций в битриксе больше.

Comment: @MyNameIs, хоть одну назовите? -)

Comment: Рейтинг CMS за первое полугодие 2013 г. http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/news/news_company/4023/ 

В рейтинге платных CMS по-прежнему лидирует 1С-Битрикс, увеличив свою долю на 2,5%, которая в итоге составила 57,23%. На втором месте свою позицию удерживает NetCat с результатом 11,56%, потеряв 4,71%. Тройку лидеров замыкает HostCMS с результатом 10,18%, потеря по сравнению с прошлым годом составила 0,39%.

Comment: @huffman, она не халявная , еще бы я за говнокод неплатил,а так я когда-то делал на битриксе сайты, http://transenergo.ru например

Comment: Проактивная защита, хотя это даже не теневое, а вполне даже настраиваемое)

Comment: я думаю автору больше интересна какая удобнее, на подобие чего создать, чем откуда код вытащить чтобы сделать такую же.